# Wordpress Multisite "The page isn’t redirecting properly" In Secondary Site Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

So if I visit the front end of the secondary site it is broken but visitable without a redirect error, but if I try to go to the dashboard for the secondary site I get the error "The page isn’t redirecting properly" / "redirected you too many times".

I have checked the following things I have seen in similar questions that solved this issue:

- the siteurl and home URL in the wp_2 options database to make sure they match and have same https
- Tried disabling all plugins
- Deleting the htaccess file

The main site front end and dashboard work without any issues.

I am using the trailing multi site name vs the subdomain if that makes any difference.

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you use Cloudflare by any chance? If you do, have you checked the SSL status for each of those domains?